# Highcharts not displaying JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, highcharts

What is the possible implementation of a Highchart(bar chart) if i have a JSON format like this..

```
{
"FRUITS": {
    "FR_ACCEPTED": 1,
    "FR_REJECTED": 0,
    "FR_PENDING": 1
},
"VEGETABLS": {
    "VEG_ACCEPTED": 0,
    "VEG_REJECTED": 0,
    "VEG_PENDING": 2
},
"GRAINS": {
    "GR_ACCEPTED": 0,
    "GR_REJECTED": 0,
    "GR_PENDING": 2
}
```

}

Comment: What did you try ? Where is you code ?

Comment: expanding your question is make us comfortable to help you.. where is the source?

Comment: I haven't tried.But would like to know how can I implement in angular js

Comment: You need to parse your json to correct from, I mean fields names and sctructure.

Comment: Thanks. @Sebastian Bochan What could be your suggestion for changing this JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example ,they can create the barchart by having JSON value..http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2072a9/creating-bar-chart-from-d3js-using-json-data/